# element-wise operations on a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

If you have a sparse matrix X:

```
>> print type(X)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

...How can you sum the squares of each element in each row, and save them into a list? For example:

```
>>print X.todense()
[[0 2 0 2]
 [0 2 0 1]]
```

How can you turn that into a list of sum of squares of each row:

```
[[0²+2²+0²+2²]
 [0²+2²+0²+1²]]
```

or:
`[8, 5]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the csr matrix has a `.sum` method (relying on the dot product) which works well, so what you need is the squaring. The simplest solution is to create a copy of the sparse matrix, square its data and then sum it:

```
squared_X = X.copy()
# now square the data in squared_X
squared_X.data **= 2

# and sum each row:
squared_sum = squared_X.sum(1)
# and delete the squared_X:
del squared_X
```

If you really must save the space, I guess you could just replace `.data` and then replace it back, something along:

```
X.sum_duplicate() # make sure, not sure if this happens with normal usage.
old_data = X.data.copy()
X.data **= 2
squared_sum = X.sum(1)
X.data = old_data
```

**EDIT**: There is actually another nice way, as the csr matrix has a `.multiply` method for elementwise multiplication:

```
squared_sum = X.multiply(X).sum(1)
```

---

Addition:
**Elementwise operations** are thus easily done by accessing `csr.data` which stores the values for all nonzero elements. *NOTE:* I guess `.sum_duplicates()` may be necessary, I am not sure what kind of operations would make it necessary.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the difference between copying the matrix (example 1) and copying the data (example 2). What are the implications of each method?

Comment: There is no real difference. In the second case you just save the copy of X.indptr and X.indices, if you are really short on memory it may be a point, and it should be a little faster too. But generally I would use the first option since I think the other is just unnecessary magic.

Comment: @Zach added `.multiply` method, which actually is very nice I think for this problem.

Comment: Can we not do the square for rectangle matrices?